# Flutter integration_test: How to simulate mouse operation like right/scroll/left clicks?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Implementing some integration_test for flutter-web application wherein I'm trying to simulate mouse operation like right/scroll/left clicks?

After much googling tried with the below code, seems to be like TestPointer doesn't have click operation:

```
final TestPointer testPointer = TestPointer(1, PointerDeviceKind.mouse); 
  await tester.sendEventToBinding(testPointer.hover());
```

Please correct me if am missing something or any suggestion or docs reference would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right Click can be solved by passing the Secondary Mouse Button value to tap.

int button = rightButton ? kSecondaryMouseButton : kPrimaryButton;

await tester.tap(place, buttons: button);